# How to use facebook api version v2.2 instead of v2.4

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a facebook web app & it's working fine on older version of the Facebook API. Today, I have created a new app. I am trying to use that old codes into my new app based on the updated API. I want to use facebook api v2.2. Is it possible to mention its version while creating a new app?

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to use the latest version of the API. Facebook especially, regularly deprecate and replace code. v2.2 may be out of date and stop working within a year.

Comment: Yes i agree with you it's good idea to use the latest version but in my current situation i dont like to use latest version.

Comment: What do you need in v2.2 that doesn't exists in the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

You can only use v2.2 with an App created before v2.3 was introduced. You can only upgrade to a newer version, but never to an older one.

Btw, creating an App with an older API version would be a very bad idea anyway, better create something that works with the latest API.

Comment: In general we agreed latest version is good just some condition our own app use old function of api that deprecate that is why we want back